# Setting date format parameter on a sqoop-import job

Tags: date, hadoop, sqoop, parquet

I am having trouble casting a date column to a string using sqoop-import from an oracle database to an HDFS parquet file. I am using the following:

```
sqoop-import -Doraoop.oracle.session.initialization.statements="alter session set nls_date_format='YYYYMMDD'"
```

My understanding is that this should execute the above statement before it begins transferring data. I have also tried

```
-Duser.nls_date_format="YYYYMMDD"
```

But this doesn't work either, the resulting parquet file still contains the original date format as listed in the table. If it matters, I am running these in a bash script and also casting the same date columns to string using `--map-column-java "MY_DATE_COL_NAME=String"`What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am also facing this issue with Sqoop 1.4.7-cdh6.1.0. I am directly importing tables into Hive in textfile format.

Answer (score 1):

Source: [SqoopUserGuide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html)

Oracle JDBC represents DATE and TIME SQL types as TIMESTAMP values. Any DATE columns in an Oracle database will be imported as a TIMESTAMP in Sqoop, and Sqoop-generated code will store these values in java.sql.Timestamp fields.

You can try casting date to String while importing within the query.

**For Example**

```
sqoop import -- query 'select col1, col2, ..., TO_CHAR(MY_DATE_COL_NAME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM TableName WHERE $CONDITIONS'
```